# Move sprite with velocity to follow finger

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way to use velocity to make a sprite follow your finger? I want a sprite to follow my finger but I don't want it to be drag and drop. I want it to be able to interact with other sprite with the delegate properties.

For example: I want a ball to reset when it hits a wall.
I have the code set up to reset the ball. When the ball hits the wall, it doesn't reset. I put in a print statement to see if its registering the collisions. When the ball hits the wall, it prints the statement.

Thats a problem with how I'm making the ball move, right?

Or could there be an error with my code.

Code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit



class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()
    var danger1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var danger2 = SKSpriteNode()
    var goal = SKSpriteNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger1 = self.childNode(withName: "danger1") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger2 = self.childNode(withName: "danger2") as! SKSpriteNode
        goal = self.childNode(withName: "goal") as! SKSpriteNode

        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 0

        danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: danger1.size)
        danger1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        danger1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        danger2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: danger2.size)
        danger2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        danger2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

        goal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: goal.size)
        goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
        goal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false


        setupPhysics()
        startGame()
    }
    func setupPhysics() {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }


    func startGame() {
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 550)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            ball.position.x = location.x
            ball.position.y = location.y

        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory {
            print("Contact")
        } else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory {
            print("goal contact")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you should use velocity instead of position.

You have to apply the difference of the positions. In order to make it a bit smoother, you should also apply weight to your velocity.

This has not been tested and looks more like pseudo code, but that's what you should do basically.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let destination = touch.location(in: self)
        let position = ball.position
        let direction = destination - position // the vector of the difference
        let weight = 0.95 // 0.0 to 1.0 

        ball.velocity = CGVector(direction * weight) // multiply the vector by the weight
    }
}
```

You should do this in a loop that runs every frame and use a flag to see if there's a finger touching the screen, because it doesn't apply velocity when you touch the screen but don't move your finger.

Comment: I just tried using that code to see what I'd need to do and an error pops up saying Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'CGPoint' operands
You just can't subtract destination and position.

I am assuming you need to actually define the "-" operator in a function?

Comment: You can do so, or decompose the operation on each dimension. Try to replace that with ``let direction = CGVector(x: destination.x - position.x, y: destination.y - position.y)``.  You may do the same thing on the factor.